# What went wrong with memory?

Tags: c++

My code terminates unexpectedly after running part of it. I know there is a memory problem, but which sentence is wrong?
Visual studio 2019 said Read access permissions conflict.

This is a practice experiment in our school

```
#include <iostream> 
using std::cin;
using std::cout;
using std::endl;
using std::string;
struct address
{
    string name;
    long long phone_number;
    long long classroom;
    long long dormitory;
};
class book
{
protected:
    address* a = NULL;
    int listsize;
    int arraylength;
public:
    book();
    ~book()；
    bool find(string &c);
};
book::book()
{
    listsize = 0;
    arraylength = 50;
    a = new address[arraylength];
    for (int i = 0; i < arraylength; i++)
    {
        a[i].classroom = 0; a[i].dormitory = 0; a[i].phone_number = 0;
    }
}
bool book::find(string &c)
{
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < listsize; i++)
    {
        if (a[i].name == c)
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}
book::~book()
{
    delete[]a;
}
int main()
{
    int nn2;
    book b;string c;
    if (nn2 == 3)
    {
        cin >> c;
        cout << b.find(c) << endl;
    }return 0;
}
```

What's wrong with me? I've been debugging all afternoon, and I realize that I need more practice

Comment: please ignore the _delete function.

Comment: 1) "_I've been debugging all afternoon_" Are you stepping through your code line-by-line, while investigating the values, **at each** execution step, taking note of when the values don't match your expectations? 2) "_please ignore the _delete function._" You are supposed to provide us with [mcve]. If we can ignore one thing, how can we know what else should we ignore? Please provide us with [mcve] then.

Comment: What's the input to reproduce the problem? Why do you pass a `book` to `b.insert(b)`? That make no sense for me. You can access `b` in `insert` with `this`

Comment: I have deleted some functions, I don't know what my error is, so I can't provide minimal reproducible example.And when I run the find function, I got an error, but I don't think the find function has some problems.

Comment: If you can't provide [mcve] we can't help. You post a code that can't be compiled and ask us to find a runtime error. How can we reproduce it?

Comment: 17
0 Evan 57298577609 1 65
0 WINNIE 37367348390 4 1
3 Evan
3 WINNIE
3 MARYAM
3 CAMERON
3 TZIVIA
0 OMAR 16447001130 6 55
3 JADEN
3 ELIZABETH
3 JOSHUA
3 Azaan
3 MARIA
0 HANNAH 94060479192 5 98
3 HEIDY
0 Axel 92066832927 3 70
3 TIFFANY

Comment: Are you aware that you are deleting all old entries with `delete []b.a; b.a = new address[2*arraylength];` in `void book::insert(book &b)`? You should use stl containers to avoid such problems. Use [std::vector](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector)

Comment: `address* a = NULL;` in a class declaration rather than as a constructor initialiser. Is that even legal?

Comment: @iwarv Of course, why not?

Comment: @Thomas Sablik. I am using an older compiler obviously. A bit behind on all of you.

Comment: @iwarv Then you should upgrade the compiler, since such initialization was possible since C++11: for 8 years, at the very least.

Comment: @lllsy "_I can't provide minimal reproducible example_" Did you read the link? It explains what [mcve] is, and the techniques in making it.

Comment: @Algirdas No can do. Workplace dictates what we use. I'll bow out. Over to you guys.

Comment: I've changed the code to make it look clearer

Comment: Please do not put information like example input into the comments, [edit] the question instead!

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show us what kind of debugging you've done.  I expect you to have run your [mcve] within Valgrind or a similar checker, and to have investigated with a debugger such as GDB, for example.  Ensure you've enabled a full set of compiler warnings, too.  What did the tools tell you, and what information are they missing?  And read Eric Lippert's [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Answer (score 5):

your probleme is caused by this :

```
book::~book()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < arraylength; i++)
    {
        delete []a;
    }
}
```

you delete several times the table

Comment: yes，i find it ，but there is still some wrong，When I debug it, it gets stuck in return false

Comment: I've changed the code to make it look clearer

Comment: @Illsy Sorry, I said I'd bow out, but I cannot see where `listsize` gets set other than to zero in the constructor. If it is indeed zero for the lifetime of execution, then your `Book::find()` isn't going to find anything. To me it seems that `listsize` is superfluous. Get rid and just use `arraylength`.

Answer (score 0):

I cleaned up your code, applied the rules of modern c++ and removed all unused functions. This is the result

```
#ifndef ADDRESS_BOOK_H
#define ADDRESS_BOOK_H

#include <string>
#include <vector>

struct address
{
    std::string name;
    long long phone_number;
    long long classroom;
    long long dormitory;
};

class book
{
protected:
    std::vector<address> a;
public:
    void insert();
    bool find(std::string c);
};
#endif

#include <iostream>

void book::insert() {
    a.emplace_back();
    std::cin >> a.back().name >> a.back().phone_number >> a.back().classroom >> a.back().dormitory;
}

bool book::find(std::string c)
{
    return std::find_if(std::begin(a), std::end(a), [&c](const auto &a) {
        return a.name == c;
    }) != std::end(a);
}

#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    int nn1;
    std::cin >> nn1;
    book b; 
    std::string c;
    for(int i = 0; i < nn1; i++) {
        int nn2;
        std::cin >> nn2;
        if (nn2 == 0)
            b.insert();
        else if (nn2 == 1)
        {
            std::cin >> c;
        }
        else 
            std::cout << std::boolalpha << b.find(c) << '\n';
    }
    return 0;
}
```

You should avoid naked `new` and `delete`. Avoid C-style arrays. Use a [std::vector](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector). Then you can use default constructors and destructor. You don't have to manage the size of your list. Use stl algorithms like [std::find_if](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find)

The input

```
17 
0 Evan 57298577609 1 65 
0 WINNIE 37367348390 4 1 
3 Evan 
3 WINNIE 
3 MARYAM 
3 CAMERON 
3 TZIVIA 
0 OMAR 16447001130 6 55 
3 JADEN 
3 ELIZABETH 
3 JOSHUA 
3 Azaan 
3 MARIA 
0 HANNAH 94060479192 5 98 
3 HEIDY 
0 Axel 92066832927 3 70 
3 TIFFANY
```

doesn't work with the code you provided. You have to enter the number of actions you want to do (17). Then you can choose the action.

- 0 - you can insert a new element.
- 1 - you can set the search string.
- else - you search for the term.

An input like `3 Evan` stops your program from working correctly. A correct input would be

```
4 
0 Evan 57298577609 1 65 
0 WINNIE 37367348390 4 1 
1 Evan
3
```

If you want your input to work you have to change the program to

```
#ifndef ADDRESS_BOOK_H
#define ADDRESS_BOOK_H

#include <string>
#include <vector>

struct address
{
    std::string name;
    long long phone_number;
    long long classroom;
    long long dormitory;
};

class book
{
protected:
    std::vector<address> a;
public:
    void insert();
    bool find(std::string c);
};
#endif

#include <iostream>

void book::insert() {
    a.emplace_back();
    std::cin >> a.back().name >> a.back().phone_number >> a.back().classroom >> a.back().dormitory;
}

bool book::find(std::string c)
{
    return std::find_if(std::begin(a), std::end(a), [&c](const auto &a) {
        return a.name == c;
    }) != std::end(a);
}

#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    int nn1;
    std::cin >> nn1;
    book b; 
    std::string c;
    for(int i = 0; i < nn1; i++) {
        int nn2;
        std::cin >> nn2;
        if (nn2 == 0)
            b.insert();
        else if (nn2 == 3)
        {
            std::cin >> c;
            std::cout << std::boolalpha << b.find(c) << '\n';
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: however,after you input 3 Evan,the program will be terminated

Comment: @Illsy yes, I described it in my answer. Your input doesn't work with your program. I added a solution for this program.

Comment: you can see my code which had been updated,and when I debug it, it gets stuck in return false

Comment: @lllsy I don't understand. For me it works without infinite loop, errors, segmentation fault or terminate: https://wandbox.org/permlink/88R5ZMUGIhLXsZ2j

Comment: Thank you very much.But could you help me see What's wrong with my code,I just corrected it, but there's still a mistake.It's on top

Comment: @lllsy Why don't you use my code? It works.

Comment: yes,yes,i konw,but But I still had doubts about my code,you know it's very uncomfortable

Comment: @lllsy The problem was that you read an `int` but provided a `string`. That blocked the input. Your current code causes undefined behvaior because you read an uninitialized value in `if (nn2 == 3)`.

Comment: oh yeah,i am silly.ありがとう

Comment: See my comment on @Landstalker's answer. How can `Book::find()` ever work? I don't see `listsize` being initialised anywhere other than the ctor. I think @Illsy should just use `arraylength` in that loop.

Comment: @iwarv The code was changed. At the beginning it made sense. Now the whole code makes no sense. You can check the edit history.